# Powershell, SCCM and committing

Tags: powershell, sccm

Digging around, I created a script used to add query-type rules to existing collections, more or less like:

```
$CommonParameters = @{
    ComputerName = "servername"
    Namespace = 'root\sms\site_111'
}

$CollName="Devices_AppName_FR_01.00.00_R2.000_Standard"
$TargetCollType=2
$computer="servername"
$Codesite="111"

$PCColl=GWMI @CommonParameters -Query "SELECT CollectionID FROM     SMS_Collection WHERE Name = '$NewName' AND CollectionType = '$TargetCollType'"
$PCColl.get()

$PCRule =     ([WMIClass]"\\$($computer)\root\sms\site_$($Codesite):SMS_CollectionRuleQuery").    CreateInstance()
$PCRule.QueryExpression="select * from SMS_R_System where     SMS_R_System.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup = 'DN' and SMS_R_System.SystemOUName =     'F.Q.D.N./Desktops/Something'"
$PCRule.RuleName = "test"
$PCColl.AddMembershipRule($PCRule) 

$PCRule =     ([WMIClass]"\\$($computer)\root\sms\site_$($Codesite):SMS_CollectionRuleQuery").    CreateInstance()
$PCRule.QueryExpression="select * from SMS_R_System where     SMS_R_System.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup = 'DN' and SMS_R_System.SystemOUName =     'F.Q.D.N./Desktops/SomethingElse'"
$PCRule.RuleName = "test2"
$PCColl.AddMembershipRule($PCRule) 

$PCSchedule =     ([WMIClass]"\\$($computer)\Root\sms\site_$($Codesite):SMS_ST_RecurInterval").Cre    ateInstance()
$PCSchedule.DaySpan = "7"
$PCSchedule.StartTime =     [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDmtfDateTime((Get-Date))
$PCColl.RefreshSchedule=$PCSchedule
$PCColl.Put()
```

So, synthetically, getting the collection, adding 2 new membershiprules, updating the schedule and committing changes.

Checking afterwards the collection, I could see the Schedule properly modified (DaySpan to 7 days) but the membership rules seemed not added.

After different modifications and checks, the following code works :

```
$CommonParameters = @{
    ComputerName = "servername"
    Namespace = 'root\sms\site_111'
}

$CollName="Devices_AppName_FR_01.00.00_R2.000_Standard"
$TargetCollType=2
$computer="servername"
$Codesite="111"

$PCColl=GWMI @CommonParameters -Query "SELECT CollectionID FROM SMS_Collection WHERE Name = '$NewName' AND CollectionType = '$TargetCollType'"
$PCColl.get()

$PCSchedule = ([WMIClass]"\\$($computer)\Root\sms\site_$($Codesite):SMS_ST_RecurInterval").CreateInstance()
$PCSchedule.DaySpan = "7"
$PCSchedule.StartTime = [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDmtfDateTime((Get-Date))
$PCColl.RefreshSchedule=$PCSchedule
$PCColl.Put()

$PCRule = ([WMIClass]"\\$($computer)\root\sms\site_$($Codesite):SMS_CollectionRuleQuery").CreateInstance()
$PCRule.QueryExpression="select * from SMS_R_System where SMS_R_System.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup = 'DN' and SMS_R_System.SystemOUName = 'F.Q.D.N./Desktops/Something'"
$PCRule.RuleName = "test"
$PCColl.AddMembershipRule($PCRule) 

$PCRule = ([WMIClass]"\\$($computer)\root\sms\site_$($Codesite):SMS_CollectionRuleQuery").CreateInstance()
$PCRule.QueryExpression="select * from SMS_R_System where SMS_R_System.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup = 'DN' and SMS_R_System.SystemOUName = 'F.Q.D.N./Desktops/SomethingElse'"
$PCRule.RuleName = "test2"
$PCColl.AddMembershipRule($PCRule)
```

So, synthetically, getting the collection, updating the schedule, committing changes and adding 2 new membershiprules.

My concern is not understanding why I don't have to commit, using .Put() method.
That seemed so logical to me (having to commit changes), especially reading [this](http://cm12sdk.net/?p=1028).

Comment: I hope I am not misunderstanding the concepts so I just put this as a comment but the way I understood it is: If you take a wmi class and just modify values, like you really change the RefershSchedule here with an assign, then you need a put to commit. This is like the most basic operation, really operating on the DB. But if you call AddMembershipRule you do not assign but invoke a method, This is far more high level, so the method does the commiting (and all other work) but ofc only works if a dedicated method exists for the given use case.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason you're using WMI to do this rather than the [ConfigManager SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh948960.aspx)?  I haven't found any official guidance from Microsoft on which APIs are going to be well-supported in the future.  However, I'm pretty sure the SCCM Admin Console is using the SDK.  I have also found that objects produced by the [official SCCM cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj821831(v=sc.20).aspx) can be manipulated using the SDK. Because of this I abandoned WMI in favor of the SDK and Powershell Cmdlets.

Comment: @Syberdoor : your understanding and my observation meet. I think I'll stick to it.

Comment: @alx9r : it may be related to how is configured SCCM at my current client but what took 20 seconds when coded using Powershell SCCM CMDLETS, took 2 seconds when coded using Powershell, WMI and WQL. And, IMHO, it is so simple to add remote capabilities to scripts when coded using Powershell, WMI and WQL.